# Send wear's data to unity through Android handheld

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, wear-os, google-cardboard, sony-smartwatch

Hi I am student who develop game that using wear and handheld.

I want to send wear's data to unity.
So I passed data wear to handheld. (I did it already)

Then handheld get data and send unity.

I want to use Unity Android Plugin because I don't know another way to send data to unity from wear.

But If I make Android project to library file(.jar), and set Unity plugin(put AndroidPlugin.jar, Manifest.xml to Unity and set Script) it is not work.

Unity apk file is just quit before start.

How I have to do???

And Somebody knows about GoogleUnityActivity??? I searched about it but there is no info.

Please answer my question...

Comment: I have never heard of GoogleUnityActivity before (is it your activity?). Unity runs in UnityPlayerActivity. Anyways, at this moment what you need to do is start Logcat on your PC, connect the device and start the app on your device. Let it crash and Logcat will show what cause the crash. Edit your question and add the Logcat logs so that we can help you.

Comment: Hi thank you for answer!  GoogleUnityActivity is google's their own UnityPlayerActivity called GoogleUnityActivity...I have never heard about this too.... So Im using UnityPlayerActivity now. And I want to capture android Logcat but apk file can not see logcat because it is not Android project and not unity project. Instead, I will add my code !